# How can I constructor my Helpers function into this.function name

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

Hi I'm using addonis js framework and I try to constructor my helper function . now when I want to use my helper function my code look like this

```
const HelpersValidate = use('App/Helpers/Validate');
const HelpersUploadImage = use('App/Helpers/UploadImage');
const checkvalidate = await HelpersValidate.checkValidate(adminData, rules, messages);
const uploadImage = await HelpersUploadImage.uploadImage(image, path, width, height);
```

I've to call  HelpersValidate, HelpersUploadImage before I use my function Here is what I try . I try to add constructor but it's notwokring my problem are here . ( in my controller )

```
constructor() {
        this.HelpersValidate = HelpersValidate;
        this.HelpersUploadImage = HelpersUploadImage;
    }
```

Here is what I want my code look like

```
await this.checkValidate(adminData, rules, messages);
await this.uploadImage(image, path, width, height);
```

here is my Helper

```
class HelpersUploadImage {
    static async uploadImage(image, path, width, height) {
        //some code
    }
}
module.exports = HelpersUploadImage;
```

Comment: There is no point in using classes here.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks u mean in my helper ?

Comment: @SLaks my error show checkValidate is not a function

Comment: Why do you expect `this.checkValidate` to exist? You never create that

Comment: I just want to use this.checkValidate instead of  HelpersValidate.checkValidate

Answer (score 0):

To call `this.checkValidate`, it must exist.

Assigning `this.HelpersValidate` does not create a `this.checkValidate` property .

You need to create a property with  the same name that you use.